# R - Lasso Regression - different Lambda per regressor

Tags: r, regression, glmnet, lars

I want to do the following:

1) OLS regression (no penalization term) to get beta coefficients $b_{j}^{*}$; $j$ stands for the variables used to regress. I do this by

```
lm.model = lm(y~ 0 + x)
betas    = coefficients(lm.model)
```

2) Lasso regression with a penalization term, the selection criteria shall be the Bayesian Information Criteria (BIC), given by

$$\lambda _{j} = \frac{\log (T)}{T|b_{j}^{*}|}$$

where $j$ stands for the variable/regressor number, $T$ for the number of observations, and $b_{j}^{*}$ for the initial betas obtained in step 1). I want to have regression results for this specific $\lambda_j$ value, which is different for each regressor used. Hence if there are three variables, there will be three different values $\lambda_j$.

The OLS-Lasso optimization problem is then given by

$$\underset{b\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{n} }{min} = \left \{ \sum_{t=1}^{T}(y_{t}-b^{\top} X_{t}  )^{2} + T\sum_{j=1}^{m} ( \lambda_{t}|b_{j}| )\right \}$$

How can I do this in R with either the lars or glmnet package? I cannot find a way to specify lambda and I am not 100% sure if I get the correct results if I run

```
lars.model <- lars(x,y,type = "lasso", intercept = FALSE)
predict.lars(lars.model, type="coefficients", mode="lambda")
```

I appreciate any help here.

---

**Update:**

I have used the following code now:

```
fits.cv = cv.glmnet(x,y,type="mse",penalty.factor = pnlty)
lmin    = as.numeric(fits.cv[9]) #lambda.min
fits    = glmnet(x,y, alpha=1, intercept=FALSE, penalty.factor = pnlty)
coef    = coef(fits, s = lmin)
```

In line 1 I use cross validation with my specified penalty factor ($\lambda _{j} = \frac{\log (T)}{T|b_{j}^{*}|}$), which is different for each regressor. 
Line 2 selects the "lambda.min" of fits.cv, which is the lambda that gives minimum mean cross-validation error.
Line 3 performs a lasso fit (`alpha=1`) on the data. Again I used the penalty factor $\lambda$.
Line 4 extracts the coefficients from fits which belong to the "optimal" $\lambda$ chosen in line 2.

Now I have the beta coefficients for the regressors which depict the optimal solution of the minimization problem

$$\underset{b\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{n} }{min} = \left \{ \sum_{t=1}^{T}(y_{t}-b^{\top} X_{t}  )^{2} + T\sum_{j=1}^{m} ( \lambda_{t}|b_{j}| )\right \}$$

with a penalty factor $\lambda _{j} = \frac{\log (T)}{T|b_{j}^{*}|}$. The optimal set of coefficients is most likely a subset of the regressors which I initially used, this is a consequence of the Lasso method which shrinks down the number of used regressors.

Is my understanding and the code correct?

Comment: You can use LATEX markup in your post, enclosed in dollar signs. `$\alpha$` becomes $\alpha$. Please make this, as it will make people more easily able to understand your question, and therefore answer it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the `glmnet` documentation (`?glmnet`), we see that it is possible to perform differential shrinkage. This gets us at least part-way to answering OP's question.

> `penalty.factor`: Separate penalty factors can be applied to each coefficient. This is a number that multiplies `lambda` to allow differential shrinkage. Can be 0 for some variables, which implies no shrinkage, and that variable is always included in the model. Default is 1 for all variables (and implicitly infinity for variables listed in `exclude`). Note: the penalty factors are internally rescaled to sum to `nvars`, and the `lambda` sequence will reflect this change.

To fully answer the question, though, I think that there are two approaches available to you, depending on what you want to accomplish.

1. Your question is how to apply differential shrinking in `glmnet` and retrieve the coefficients for a specific value $\lambda$. Supplying `penalty.factor` s.t. some values are not 1 achieves differential shrinkage at any value of $\lambda$. To achieve shrinkage s.t. the shrinkage for each $b_j$ is $\phi_j= \frac{\log T}{T|b_j^*|}$, we just have to do some algebra. Let $\phi_j$ be the penalty factor for $b_j$, what would be supplied to `penalty.factor`. From the documentation, we can see that these values are re-scaled by a factor of $C\phi_j=\phi^\prime_j$ s.t. $m=C\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\log T}{T|b^*_j|}$. This means that $\phi_j^\prime$ replaces $\phi_j$ in the below optimization expression. So solve for $C$, supply the values $\phi_j^\prime$ to `glmnet`, and then extract coefficients for $\lambda=1$. I would recommend using `coef(model, s=1, exact=T)`.
2. The second is the "standard" way to use `glmnet`: One performs repeated $k$-fold cross-validation to select $\lambda$ such that you minimize out-of-sample MSE. This is what I describe  below in more detail. The reason we use CV and check *out-of-sample* MSE is because *in-sample* MSE will always be minimized for $\lambda=0$, i.e. $b$ is an ordinary MLE. Using CV while varying $\lambda$ allows us to estimate how the model performs on *out-of-sample* data, and select a $\lambda$ that is optimal (in a specific sense).

That `glmnet` call doesn't specify a $\lambda$ (nor should it, because it computes the entire $\lambda$ trajectory by default for performance reasons). `coef(fits,s=something)` will return the coefficients for the $\lambda$ value `something`. But no matter the choice of $\lambda$ you provide, the result will reflect the differential penalty that you applied in the call to fit the model.

The standard way to select an optimal value of $\lambda$ is to use `cv.glmnet`, rather than `glmnet`. Cross-validation is used to select the amount of shrinkage which minimizes out-of-sample error, while the specification of `penalty.factor` will shrink some features more than others, according to your weighting scheme.

This procedure optimizes

$$
\underset{b\in \mathbb{R}^{m} }{\min} \sum_{t=1}^{T}(y_{t}-b^{\top} X_{t}  )^{2} + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{m} ( \phi_{j}|b_{j}| )
$$

where $\phi_j$ is the penalty factor for the $j^{th}$ feature (what you supply in the `penalty.factor` argument). (This is slightly different from your optimization expression; note that some of the subscripts are different.) Note that the $\lambda$ term is the same across all features, so the only way that some features are shrunk more than others is through $\phi_j$. Importantly, $\lambda$ and $\phi$ are not the same; $\lambda$ is scalar and $\phi$ is a vector! In this expression, $\lambda$ is fixed/assumed known; that is, optimization will pick the optimal $b$, not the optimal $\lambda$.

This is basically the motivation of `glmnet` as I understand it: to use penalized regression to estimate a regression model that is not overly-optimistic about its out-of-sample performance. If this is your goal, perhaps this is the right method for you after all.

Comment: +1 This is correct. I will also add that the regularization of regression can be viewed as a bayesian prior, i.e. maximum a posteriori (MAP) is regularized maximum liklihood (ML). Working in that framework gives oneself more flexibility in regularization should it be needed.

Comment: If I run 
`pnlty = log(24)/(24*betas); 
fits = glmnet(x,y, alpha=1, intercept=FALSE, penalty.factor = pnlty)` 
how do I then extract the regressor betas which correspond to the lambda that I specified, as the lambda is different for every risk factor?

Comment: For what I want to do, can't I do this:
`fits = glmnet(x,y, alpha=1, intercept=FALSE, penalty.factor = pnlty)` (pnlty is a vector specifying the penalty for each regressor)
and select the coefficients for lambda.min, which I get from 
`coef(fits.cv, s = "lambda.min")`?
Hence: `coef(fits, s=xxx)`? xxx being lambda.min

Comment: @user777: I updated my original post. If you could please have a look if my understanding and procedure is now correct.

Comment: I understand the difference between my initial optimization problem and the solution I suggested in my update. 
Is there a way to exactly solve the initial problem with the glmnet package? From my understanding, the glment equation for lasso doesn't incorporate the $T$ in front of the second term of the optimization problem. Besides, should the minimization not produce different beta values and not minimize the MSE w.r.t. $\lambda$?

Comment: I meant that lasso tries to minimize the optimization function (see my original post) with respect to the betas. it will deliver a combination of betas for which the function is minimal. That's implied by $\underset{b\epsilon \mathbb{R}^{n} }{min}$. But glmnet minimises MSE with respect to $\lambda$. This is more of a general understanding issue from my side. I do not fully understand why lambda is varied to minimize MSE, although the $\beta$ coefficients are supposed to be varied to reach the minimum. Maybe I am comparing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @Dom It dawned on me a bit too late that there's an obvious way to get exactly what you want using `glmnet`. See my revised answer.

Comment: Beware of customizing the penalty separately for each predictor.  That would amount to nothing more than stepwise variable selection in some cases.  Penalized regression decreases mean squared error by assuming a very limited number of penalty parameters and borrowing information across predictors.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for the comment! It seems that using different penalties to each predictor amounts to a Bayesian model which assumes a different prior for each parameter. That doesn't strike me as posing a unique hazard over Bayesian inference generally. Also, could you elaborate on how penalized regression borrows information across predictors? I'm not sure I fully grasp how that's the case in such a scenario.

Comment: For example using a single $\lambda$ with a quadratic penalty function you are simultaneously shrinking all the coefficients.  Allowing penalties to "float" without pre-specifying the relative penalties is analogous to doing Bayesian modeling where you update the priors after peeking at the data.

Comment: Now this update has made me understand my issue. Well done!

Comment: @Dom Glad to help! Sorry that it took so long for me to get it there. This is not a use of `glmnet` that I'd encountered before.